# How to invert a css clip-path or animate hard-stops in SVG radial gradients

Tags: css, svg

It seems that generally a css clip-path is used to hide beginning at the edges of an element. I can use something like this:

`clip-path:circle(70% at center);`

and get something like this:

[image]

Is there a way I can invert that? I want my result to be something like this:

[image]

I want to clip the center of the image, not the edges. It's an SVG, so I tried something like this pen, animating a radial gradient: http://codepen.io/ethanclevenger91/pen/myMYwQ

But that didn't work like expected. There's the animated one and then one with what I assume the final step of the animation cycle should look like, but it doesn't. Any light on either of these would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use a still use a clipPath if you use it in its url form i.e. as svg markup. Draw the path outer rectangle clockwise and the inner ellipse (using two or more elliptical arcs) anticlockwise, drawing everything as a single path together with [clip-rule="evenodd"](http://www.w3.org/TR/SVG/masking.html#ClipRuleProperty)

Alternatively you could use a `<mask>`. This is a simpler, but slower solution. Draw a white ellipse within the mask area and that part of the mask will be opaque.

Comment: The ultimate hope is to animate this in a sort of radial reveal. Not sure how I would grab just a portion of the path and change it's coordinates over time. You could manually get the points for every frame, but that seems like more work than its worth.

Comment: Sounds more like mask might be easier for that use case, but you could certainly SMIL animate the path in the former case.

Answer (score 0):

So here's what ended up happening:

Since the background I was trying to match was a solid color, I gave the circles a stroke double their radius (since stroke is applied centered on the edge of the object) and then applied a clip-path the size of the object. Then I animated the stroke to 0. Will update with a link to the application when it's live.